# Differentiate between a scroll that the user is performing and a scroll WPF is trying to do in a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with a bunch of rows in it. When I scroll down and click refresh, my scroll bar defaults to the top of the page. But I want my scroll bar to remember the scroll position after the refresh.

My xaml looks like this.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="inpatientorderGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding InpatientOrdersList,  IsAsync=True}" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollChangeHandler">
```

my xaml.cs file looks like this.

```
private void ScrollChangeHandler(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs scrollChangeEvent)
        {
            if (scrollChangeEvent.VerticalOffset > 0 || scrollChangeEvent.HorizontalOffset > 0)
            {
                dVerticalOffset = scrollChangeEvent.VerticalOffset;
                dHorizontalOffset = scrollChangeEvent.HorizontalOffset;
            }
                SetScrollViewerOffsets(dVerticalOffset, dHorizontalOffset);
        }

private void SetScrollViewerOffsets(double dVerticalOffset, double dHorizontalOffset)
        {
            DependencyObject dependencyObject = GetCurrentWorkItemDataGrid() as DependencyObject;
            if (dependencyObject != null)
            {
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(dependencyObject);
                if (scrollViewer != null)
                {
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(dHorizontalOffset);
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(dVerticalOffset);
                }
            }
        }

private ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
            {
                if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is ScrollViewer)
                {
                    scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i));
                }
                else
                {
                    scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) as DependencyObject);
                }
            }
            return scrollViewer;
        }
```

Each time I scroll down, my ScrollChangeHandler is called and I get the vertical offset and the horizontal offset and set the srcollviewer but after that, wpf is trying to reload the page to the top and my values are being reset. Inorder to avoid that I'm performing my logic only when my offsets are > 0. This solves my original problem but I see a bug when I'm trying to manually go to the top of my page since it takes the old offsets when my scroll change event offsets are zero. How do I differntiate between a manual scroll and a scroll change that wpf is trying to do?

Comment: I wonder what is your `Refresh` Button/?? doing ? If you bind to an `observablecollection` then refresh should just add or remove items to the collection. that will not affect the whole grid to refresh.

Comment: This sounds right. Let me try this and see if this works. I will keep you posted. Thank you!

Comment: I tried binding observable collection to my Datagrid and the issue still persists.

Comment: it's better to show what `Refresh` does. Please add that to the question.

Comment: How you use your GetScrollViewer()? after reset?

Comment: @MarioWu Each time my application is refreshed, my ScrollChangeHandler is called. Right now, I hacked it a little bit by adding the if condition that I have in my code. So, when I get 0 offsets, I use the old scroll positions and set the scrollviewer in that position.